# Get base64 image from public highchart export server

Tags: javascript, base64, frontend, highcharts

Is there any way to get a base64 image (instead of png, jpg, pdf) from highcharts public export server?

server: http://export.highcharts.com/

Edit:
what I'm trying to do, is render the charts on server side and store them as base64. I'm able to do that by setting up a small web server following the instructions here highcharts.com/docs/export-module/render-charts-serverside but that means I need to host this in some place, and I'm trying to figure out if that's something I can avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is something I wanted to do from the backend and without the need of rendering the chart first, I ended up getting the image from the public export server and then convert it to base64 from the backend using RestSharp to do the request (C#)

```
public static string Render(Well well, string type)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("http://export.highcharts.com");

        StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder('the options of the chart');

        var request = new RestRequest("/", Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        request.AddParameter("content", "options");
        request.AddParameter("options", json);
        request.AddParameter("constr", "Chart");
        request.AddParameter("type", "image/png");
        var response = (RestResponse) client.Execute(request);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(response.RawBytes);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the option `base64` in the dropdown. So probably the answer is no.

But you could get the png, jpg or whatever and use something like [base64 online](https://www.base64-image.de/) to encode it.

Comment: what I'm trying to do, is render the charts on server side and store them as base64. I'm able to do that setting up a small webserver following this instructions here http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/render-charts-serverside but that means I need to host this and I'm trying to figure out if that's something I can avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Very much late to post But you can get base64 from http://export.highcharts.com.
You need to pass below configuration in Request

```
let chartData = {
        infile: CHART_DATA,
        b64: true // Bool, set to true to get base64 back instead of binary.
        width: 600,
        constr : "Chart"
    }
```

**You can use below example**

```js
fetch("https://export.highcharts.com/", {
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/json",
  },
  "body": "{\"infile\":\"{\\n    \\\"xAxis\\\": {\\n        \\\"categories\\\": [\\n            \\\"Jan\\\",\\n            \\\"Feb\\\",\\n            \\\"Mar\\\",\\n            \\\"Apr\\\",\\n            \\\"May\\\",\\n            \\\"Jun\\\",\\n            \\\"Jul\\\",\\n            \\\"Aug\\\",\\n            \\\"Sep\\\",\\n            \\\"Oct\\\",\\n            \\\"Nov\\\",\\n            \\\"Dec\\\"\\n        ]\\n    },\\n    \\\"series\\\": [\\n        {\\n            \\\"data\\\": [1,3,2,4],\\n            \\\"type\\\": \\\"line\\\"\\n        },\\n        {\\n            \\\"data\\\": [5,3,4,2],\\n            \\\"type\\\":\\\"line\\\"\\n        }\\n    ]\\n}\\n\",\"width\":600,\"constr\":\"Chart\",\"b64\":true}",
  "method": "POST",
  "mode": "cors"
}).then(function(response) {
    // The response is a Response instance.
    return response.text();
  }).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);  //  base64 data
  }).catch(function(err) { console.log(err);})
```